# Soundcloud get last tracks

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

I read a lot of things about the Soundcloud API and how you can do pretty much anything with it, like build a new interface to upload your songs etc..

I just want to get a list of the 5 last tracks added by a user.
This is public data, since you don't need to login to view a user page, but everywhere I read you need to authenticate to do it...

is there not a simple way to do this?

I thought they'd be a way to call a url returning some xml or json with the link to the last tracks...?

Comment: hey, I tried using the both link given in accepted answer, I replaced client id with my client id, but still it says unauthorised.. Please tell me how did you fix this one?

Comment: I'm having this same issue after adding private tracks. It looks like when i call the api with no parameters it finds all the tracks, but as soon as I set limit=1, it can't find any... i have to go all the way to limit=8 to find 1 track.
How is this possible?

Comment: @Liquidchrome Sorry I haven't been using this for a while, maybe post a new question with a link to this one ... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a list of a user's tracks given their ID like this:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id={client_id}
```

To get the last 5 tracks, order by latest and set the limit at 5:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id={client_id}&order=latest&limit=5
```

Edited to add that you can also request a JSON response (instead of XML) by adding `&format=json` to the end of the query string.

Comment: I had read this, but when I try, I get a 401 error. I read in the api documentation that you have to register an application to get a client id, but I just want to get the 5 tracks of my client's soundcloud page, I don't need to create an app...

Comment: @Piero: You'll need to obtain a client ID. Whatever mechanism you'd be using to get the track info would be considered the "app" from the API's perspective, regardless of the fact you're just getting the last 5 tracks.

Comment: @Colin i am still getting unauthorized error.. please tell me how to resolve this

Comment: @VikasGupta You need to create an "app" from the soundcloud api to obtain a client id... have a look here : http://developers.soundcloud.com/